# Ubuntu 16.04 How to Delete Multiple Large File Sets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, devops

In my Ubuntu server I need to clear out some space on the hard drive. If i have multiple folders with 100 files+ in each what is the easiest way for me to see them and delete them. I am taking over someone else's work so the file structure is a bit unknown to me as well.

Thanks

Comment: Ask Ubuntu would be a more place for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

See:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/36111/whats-a-command-line-way-to-find-large-files-directories-to-remove-and-free-up

Can use `ncdu` to assist in locating large files, or manually use `du` and `sort` to do so, ie: `sudo du -sx /* 2>/dev/null | sort -n`